# Difference between transforming an image with a Color Matrix or by Bitmap.SetPixel

Tags: c#, bitmap, colormatrix

I have the following codes that transform an image's pixels:

1. Transforming using ColorMatrix

   ```
    Bitmap bmpOut = null;

   if (DisplayImage == null)
   {
       return;
   }

   bmpOut = GetBitmapFromImageSoure(OriginalImage.Source);

   Bitmap originalImage = bmpOut;
   Bitmap adjustedImage = new Bitmap(bmpOut.Width, bmpOut.Height);
   float brightness = (float)BrightnessSlider.Value;
   float contrast = (float)ContrastSlider.Value;
   float gamma = (float)GammaSlider.Value;
   float alpha = (float)AlphaSlider.Value;

   float adjustedBrightness = brightness - 1.0f;

   // create matrix that will brighten and contrast the image
   float[][] ptsArray ={
                       new float[] {contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // scale red
                       new float[] {0, contrast, 0, 0, 0}, // scale green
                       new float[] {0, 0, contrast, 0, 0}, // scale blue
                       new float[] {0, 0, 0, alpha, 0},    // scale alpha
                       new float[] {adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, adjustedBrightness, 0, 1}};    // brightness

   ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();

   imageAttributes.ClearColorMatrix();
   imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(ptsArray), ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
   imageAttributes.SetGamma(gamma, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(adjustedImage);

   g.DrawImage(originalImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, adjustedImage.Width, adjustedImage.Height)
       , 0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height,
       GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);

   this.DisplayImage.Source = ConvertToBitmapImage(adjustedImage);
   ```
2. Changing each pixel to transform to gray scale

   ```
   Bitmap original = GetBitmapFromImageSoure(OriginalImage.Source);
   Bitmap converted = (Bitmap)original.Clone();

   System.Drawing.Color c;

   for (int i = 0; i < converted.Width; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < converted.Height; j++)
       {
           c = converted.GetPixel(i, j);

           byte gray = (byte)(.299 * c.R + .587 * c.G + .114 * c.B);

           converted.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray));
       }
   }

   DisplayImage.Source = ConvertToBitmapImage(converted);
   ```

The first method is for changing the brightness, gamma, contrast of an image which is controlled by a slider and immidiatly transform the image.

While the second method takes time to proccess the same image with just a checkbox.

Why is using a color matrix faster and how does it work better than changing each pixel in a loop.

Comment: Changing internal flags that determine how the color is rendered or locking the Bitmap in memory and using the scanline to modify the color information is of course much faster that parsing the structure of a Bitmap object, finding and setting every single pixel in it. Btw, `ImageAttributes` is a disposable object.

Comment: Also, if you need to transform to gray scale an Image, you can also use a Matrix for that. Different types of matrices, actually. The combination of values depends on what the final result should be. Different *schools* there.

Comment: Get/SetPixel apply a lock on the bitmap for __every pixel__ they access. This takes a really long time. To avoid that and have full control one uses `Lockbits` (which lock only __once__) and loops over the pixels quickly. ColorMatrix is excennten or what it can do, which is a lot but not everything. (E.g. no blurring..)

Comment: so what i'm getting is that the ColorMatrix uses some king of algorithm that uses LockBits with a loop for each pixel in memory?

Comment: You mean, you'ld like to know what [GdipSetImageAttributesColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-imageattributes-flat) does, internally? What matters is: don't use `SetPixel()`. Unless you want to set a pixel, that is :). If you don't use a Matrix (can't use it everywhere), as TaW mentioned, [Bitmap.LockBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) is the tool of choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Jimi , yes i needed to know what it does internally.

Comment: ColorMatrix doesn't do much. It just holds a few numbers. The work is done in Graphics.DrawImage, i.e. in Graphics which is just Wrapper class for graphics context in GDI+. So the details of the inner workings are not documented afaik..